# Is Kant's idea of imperatives derived from stoicism?

Tags: kant, stoicism

Upon reading "The  Meditations" by Marcus Aurelius, I felt that in the author's view a man should only be concerned about the things which he has control over what he can do, i.e. duty.

> "A man's true delight is to do the things he was made for"

Is this concept not a precursor to Kant's idea of imperatives?

Comment: There's two related but distinct standards going on in your question, "derived from" and "precursor to." Stoicism is definitely a precursor to Kant in many respects. But "derived from" is not a particularly easy to answer question. My first instinct is "no" -- since Kant's philosophy is quite distinct from the Stoics and not really a derivative work, but I don't fully know what you mean when you use the phrase.

Answer (score 3):

This citation may wel be related to Kant. However, Kant is so embeded in the history of thought that this one citation is not enough to point to a real correlation. One has to know about the way stoics and Kant see e.g. human nature, duty and free will and the difference in these concepts in those two separate times to make a real comparison.